# How to reach full resolution potential with MacBook Pro 2012?

Tags: macbook-pro, display, hdmi, resolution, displayport

I have a MacBook Pro (13-inch, Mid 2012) running OS X El Capitan version 10.11.4. I am attempting to use an external display with my Dell U2715Q (has 4k capabilities). I purchased an AmazonBasics  miniDisplayPort to HDMI adapter and I am getting 1920x 1080 as my max resolution.

My question is: how can I obtain the full max resolution with my mac and monitor set up?

According to the official [website](https://support.apple.com/kb/sp649?locale=en_US) I should be able to reach 2560 x 1600:

> Dual display and video mirroring: Simultaneously supports full native
>   resolution on the built-in display and up to 2560 by 1600 pixels on an external display, both at millions of colors

Comment: Can you please change your title to "How to reach full resolution on external monitor?" As the current title indicates you want your built in monitor to display at full resolution.

Comment: you might wanna check this link out. worked for a whole lot of other people.
although it didn't work for me.
http://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/250528/macbook-pro-15-mid-2012-external-display-2560-x-1600-on-4k-screen-via-displa/250622

Answer (score 1):

HDMI is limited to 1920x1080. You will need to connect the monitor with a mini DP to DP cable.

Comment: The HDMI protocol can support 4K and higher, but maybe the HDMI input on this particular monitor is limited to HD, or the adapter is limited.  I agree, MiniDP to DP cable should solve the problem.