# Macbook Pro 15" mid 2012, external display @ 2560 x 1600 on 4K screen via DisplayPort?

Tags: resolution, displayport

[image: about this mac]

I have a Macbook Pro 15" mid 2012, and I want to add an external display running at 2560 x 1600. Given that I want a future proof display, I purchased a 4K monitor. (LG27UD88)

Of course I know it will not run 4K resolution, but I was hoping to would at least allow me to run 2560 x 1600 as supported by the NVIDIA GT650M.
Turns out I only achieve 1920 x 1080 :(

I connected with a purchased mini-DisplayPort to DisplayPort cable.
Could it be a limitation of the cable?
Will connecting via a mini-DP to HDMI cable change anything?

The 1920 x 1080 resolution is really superb and crispy, but it's a bit an expensive HD monitor...

Anyone any tips ?

Comment: I'm looking at 2 pages on Everymac to try decide, but it's not clear. The [mid 2012](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-15-mid-2012-unibody-usb3-specs.html) page just says up to 2560x1600 but gives no details. The [retina 2012](http://www.everymac.com/systems/apple/macbook_pro/specs/macbook-pro-core-i7-2.3-15-mid-2012-retina-display-specs.html) page says it can only achieve that resolution over thunderbolt, not HDMI. Neither mentions DP at all.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Well looks like I found the answer to my problem.
All I had to do was **press the Option button when selecting "Scaled"** from the Displays setting; this allowed me to select 3840 x 2160 (30Hz) and 2560 x 1440 (60Hz)

[image: display settings]

Well, to be more precise, the 2560x1440 resolution is not 60Hz but **for a weird reason it shows 59Hz** in System Information. Does anyone know how come?

[image: system information]

Comment: I'm unable to pick any resolution higher than 1280 x 720, "low resolution" or not, on my BenQ 4K EL2870U. I connect to it through an mDP-DP cable that supports 4K resolution, so I'm stumped as to why no other resolution will work.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a helpful link:

[How To Connect a 4K Monitor to a 2012 Retina MacBook Pro](https://blog.fosketts.net/2015/11/09/how-to-connect-a-4k-monitor-to-a-2012-retina-macbook-pro/)

Comment: An answer should still be useful when the link disappears e.g. put the information in the answer, if taken from somewhere else give credit and use links for extra information - also how does this differ from the accepted answer?

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different and thank you for your answer. :) Unfortunately, short answers such as this don't really provide enough detail or context to help many users. And, just providing a link isn't very helpful as it may no longer work in future. Instead, could you please edit your answer (there's an _edit_ link below it) to include a summary of the content you're linking to? This will make your answer more self-contained and help preserve it for other users in future.